# ACPI PCC probe failed while trying to install ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: drivers, nvidia, acpi

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.3 for a while now and I always get the same error when I select the install Ubuntu option, which is the next one:

[image: picture 1]

It has to be related with the graphics card for what I have seen in other questions, my laptop has a Nvidia GTX 960m.

I have been looking for solutions but I have not found anyone so far. Could anybody help me or give me some hints about what to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried booting with the `nomodeset` boot option?

Comment: Finally I got ubuntu 14.04 working just by installing 12.04 and upgrading from there to 14.04. I did it that way before seeing your answer. Thanks for your advice though, I will have it in mind for the next time a similar thing happens to me!